# Opening up Excel via Python on macOS

Tags: python, excel, macos, subprocess, xlwt

So I coded up a program that extracts data from certain websites and then exports said data to a temporary excel file(which is created at the given path if not already existing).  Below is the code for the main function.  The part I am having trouble with is starting with `book = xlwt.Workbook()` but I wanted to include everything to provide the full situation.  I coded up the program on a Windows 10 computer, and everything worked fine.  However, I need to change this to work on a mac.  I know with the mac I'm getting to at least the `browser.close()` part but after that, I have no idea if anything is working.  I am unsure if I am writing into an Excel file at all in the first place, but mostly I am having trouble figuring out how to find the path of the excel file and launching the file itself.  Can anyone help me figure out how to do the same thing I do below but just for a mac instead??

```
def main():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    option = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    browser = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()

    keyword = None
    urlList = None

    # two different lists of data I scrapped
    wi = webInfo(browser, keyword)
    mi = mobileInfo(browser, keyword)

    urlList = wi+mi

    browser.close()

    book = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet1 = book.add_sheet('sheet1')

    for i in range(len(urlList)):
        for j in range(len(urlList[i])):
            sheet1.write(i, j, urlList[i][j])

    name = "random.xls"
    book.save(name)
    book.save(TemporaryFile())

    excelFile = "C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/test/random.xls"
    excelEx = r"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/EXCEL"

    subprocess.Popen([excelEx, excelFile])
```

Comment: You need to think about which parts of your code is dependent on operating system, for example, your paths don't seem to be valid paths for macOS.

Comment: @BcK that's kinda what I figured but I have no idea what the format for macOS paths are.  I've tried to do some different ways, but I haven't found any of them to really work so I was wondering if maybe something else is the problem

Comment: This is not an excuse. Go ahead and learn how mac handles its file system and the path conventions. IMO, if you have written this code yourself, it should be pretty easy to make it work on macOS.

Comment: @BcK that's what I've been trying to do but I can't figure it out which is why I'm asking for help here.  I have very limited access to a macbook and so I'm trying to learn all this on a PC, which is why I'm finding these seemingly not-"excusable" tasks difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `os` module to deal with paths in mac if you have limited access to macOS.

For example let's assume that you want to put the output excel file into the same directory as your python file, then,

```
import os

os.chdir(os.getcwd())
name = "random.xls"
book.save(name)

excelFile = os.path.abspath('random.xls')

# just try without these lines first and open file manually
excelEx = "You need to show the excel executable at this point"
subprocess.Popen([excelEx, excelFile])
```